# Two buttons stretched to full screen on Android

Tags: android, layout, fullscreen, android-relativelayout, grid-layout

I thought it would be quite easy, but found no solution for my problem: I only want to have two buttons, one above the other. Both with screen width, both with half screen height, so they fill the screen. I tried distinct RelativeLayout and GridView solutions, but everything went wrong.

Does anyone have a solution for me?

Comment: Can you show your code? I know you feel like "everything went wrong," but for an answerer, that just means that there are a million possible problems and we have no way to figure out which it is.

Comment: Can you add more info about, specifically, what happened when "everything went wrong"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
LinearLayout

    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button

        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="One" />

    <Button

        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="Two" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The key points are layout_weight and 0dp for height.  Layout weight divides up remaining space between child controls and since each button is zero pixels, they are each given 50% of the available height - in this case, full screen if LinearLayout is the root.

Comment: @Simon: Although the effect may be the same, I'd prefer not to promote use of `px` at any time unless the end user knows what they're doing with physical screen pixels. Personally I'd use `0dp` for `layout_height` simply because it is better practice to use `dp` as a general rule.

Comment: 0px = 0pd under all circumstances, but, point taken and post edited.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```